# translating words using jQuery and Squarespace

Tags: jquery, squarespace

I'm trying to finalise the design of a website using `Squarespace`. I would like to translate two words from US english to UK english (`colour` instead of `color`), but somehow I'm stuck.

Here's the link to the page: https://www.maisonmariet.fr/collection/mm01

Using jQuery, I've been able to modify one word out of three:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".variant-option-title").text("colour:");
 });
 </script>
```

Now, when it comes to the "data-variant-option-name" and the "option value", I can't modify anything although trust me I've probably spent 4 hours trying. I hope you guys will be able to understand my issue and to help me fix it...

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: All this code shows is that you're setting the `.text()` on elements selected by class (of which there are none in the code shown).  It's not really clear what the problem is here.

Comment: Why do you want to modify `data-variant-option-name`? Looking at your page, modifying that won't change anything. I might be wrong, though. Could you explain in more detail exactly what you want to change? Maybe with some screenshots as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may helps you

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".variant-option-title").text("colour:");
$('.list').attr('data-variant-option-name', 'colour'); 

$(".list option[value='']").text('Select Colour');

 });
 </script>
<div class="variant-option" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1504692126682_213">
    <div class="variant-option-title">color:</div>
    <div class="variant-select-wrapper" data-text="Select Color" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1504692126682_349">
      <select class="list" data-variant-option-name="Color" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1504692126682_215">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <option value="White">White</option><option value="Grey">Grey</option><option value="Ivory">Ivory</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

if you want to select option value as a loop,try the below code

```
 $("select option").filter(function() {

    var val = $(this).text() ; 
   console.log(val);

})
```

If you want to change every values of drop down ,you can use this code

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".variant-option-title").text("colour:");
         $("select option").each(function() {

           var val = $(this).val() ;
           var txt = $(this).text() ; 
           var text = convertustouk(txt);
           var vals = convertustouk(val);
        $("select option[value='"+val+"']").text(text);
       $("select option[value='"+val+"']").val(vals);
        })
         });
        function convertustouk(val){
        var res = val;
        if(val =='Select Color')
        {
         res = 'Select Colour';
        }
        if(val =='Grey')
        {
         res = 'Gray';
        }
        return res;
        }
</script>
<div class="variant-option" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1504692126682_213">
    <div class="variant-option-title">color:</div>
    <div class="variant-select-wrapper" data-text="Select Color" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1504692126682_349">
      <select class="list" data-variant-option-name="Color" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1504692126682_215">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <option value="White">White</option><option value="Grey">Grey</option><option value="Ivory">Ivory</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks ubm, it's almost perfect... Both remaining words are translated, although now there's a box (top left on the screen) that appears. So, your code doesn't work directly where I would like it to, but I'm sure it's fixable. Here's a link to the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejc1ugc39juqm7j/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202017-09-06%20%C3%A0%2012.50.41.png?dl=0

Comment: I'm sorry ubm, I'm not sure I understand. Is the "select option value as a loop" comment in response to my first comment? If so, can you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to access the html since I didn't create the website from scratch but using a Squarespace template. Now, here's what happens when I try to change the drop down menu values with the code you provided: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0v1ysf4xyyz1bv/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202017-09-07%20%C3%A0%2009.12.19.png?dl=0 Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: it works! I just kept the first part of your code, because adding the "<div class="variant-option" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1504692126682_213">"... part adds a drop down menu that appears on top left of the screen. Again, thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate the help.